# Words confuse- prefecture, county and shire.

Tags: idioms

How could I distinguish the usage between the prefecture and county?
In my opinion, I think "shire" is smaller than a county or prefecture.
 
Is there any problem with my concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK, county and shire mean the same thing - a primary division of a country - but we use them slightly differently. Shire is suffixed to (usually) the county town name, as in Yorkshire, tho it sometimes gets merged somewhat: Lancaster plus shire = Lancashire. County is used for some county-names (who knows why?) and in deference to French syntax comes *before* the town name, as in County Durham. But unless we want to sound cute, we no longer use shire generically: "all over the county", not "all over the shire."

Answer (score 0):

In the US we use "county" (because, according to Alexis de Tocqueville, Americans care less for words than the French), but neither of the other two. I think it just depends on where you are.  In Canada, they have provinces. In the US, we have states.

Comment: In Louisiana (only) they are called "parishes" rather than "counties".